# Ms Access DoCmd.ApplyFilter does not get the value from my variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with leased vehicles and i am trying to make a form where you can filter out which vehicles expire in less than x months. What I did was this:

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub butFilterTruck_Click()
    Dim ED As Date
    Dim AM As Integer
    Dim AD As Date

    AM = txtM.Value
    AD = txtDate.Value

    ED = DateAdd("m", AM, AD)

    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] < ED"

End Sub
```

When I click the "filter" button access prompts me to enter a value for ED... Why is that?

The filter works if I add a date when access asks for it.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: You've included `ED` within the string, so it's reading it exactly as `ED`.  Try changing the line to `DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] < " & ED`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but it makes the entire form blank

Comment: That'll suggest the filter is working, but the filter value isn't holding the correct value for the field.  Access can be problematic with dates - parts of it uses the local date settings, while others are always US date standard.  Try changing the line to `DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] < " & CLng(ED)`.  On my test I added `AM = 1` and `AD = DateValue("10 March 2017")`.  The filter returned the one record that had a date less than 10th April 2017.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That is not the right way to do it. See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html for working properly with international dates in queries/filters. Use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] < #" & Format$(ED, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "#"`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Erik.  I always forget how to properly deal with dates in Access.

Comment: Quick update - `DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] < #" & Format$(ED, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "#"` returns an error (`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Avtalsslut] < ##04/10/2017##'.`).  Use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] <  #" & Format(ED, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"` (3rd bullet point in section 2 on link Erik provided).

Comment: You have added an extra # around the dates the date string should be #mm/dd/yyyy#

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all the help! -> DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Avtalsslut] < #" & Format(ED, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#" as Darren suggested in the "quick update" works perfectly!